# Detecting with KVO when Adjusting focus is done - not correct on iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, key-value-observing, avcapturesession

I want to take a still image with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, when adjusting focus is done, I'm using key-value observing to do so, when testing on iPhone 6+ with iOS 10 the method

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"adjustingFocus"] )
    {
        BOOL adjustingFocus = [ [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];
        if (adjustingFocus)
        {
            NSLog(@"adjusting focus started");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"adjustingFocus done");
        }
    }
}
```

some times gets called several times, the first time I detect that the focus is done the screen is blurry and so is the still image that was captured. I've noticed that in that case (blurry image) the method is called 2 more times (when starting and finishing to adjust the focus). Is there a way to detect that the focus was not properly adjusted and wait for the next call or a way for it to be called only once?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes a single focusing "event" yields a sequence of start, stop, start, stop in rapid succession as far as KVO is concerned. To mitigate this, I keep track of the timestamp when I hear about a "start" and if the next "stop" event comes in before a certain threshold of time has passed (I used 300ms), I disregard that "stop" event because I'm fairly sure another "start" will come very soon (which I also ignore because we have already "started"), and then the final "stop" that comes after that will be more than 300ms after the first "start" so I consider that to be the true end of that focusing event.